# Follow button using AJAX only updates first div

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I have a _user.html.erb partial that I am rendering on my Users#Index action with a form embedded to allow following and unfollowing of each user. I also have accompanying create.js.erb and destroy.js.erb files in my relationships controller to handle the AJAX. Right now I have to refresh the page in order to see the changes made by clicking the "follow/unfollow" button next to a users name except the first user's record behaves correctly.

_user.html.erb

```
<div id ="follow_form">
    <% if current_user.following?(user) %>
      <%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id),
             html: { method: :delete },
             remote: true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large" %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: user.id),
             remote: true) do |f| %>
        <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
        <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

---

destroy.js.erb

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

---

here is a link to my users_controller.rb https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9608208 and my relationships_controller.rb https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9608284

I've tried changing the div to something dynamic like

```
<div id ="follow_form_<%= user.id %>">
```

But when I make the same change to the javascript like this

```
$("#follow_form_<%= user.id %>").find.html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
```

it doesn't seem to work.

I've been trying to figure out how to pass the user.id attribute into the javascript but am falling flat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was in my _follow_form.html.erb partial.
I had to change

```
<div id="follow_form">
```

to

```
<div id="follow_form_<%= @user.id %>">
```

I thought I only needed to make the change in the _user.html.erb partial but I was wrong. My current user partial uses the same div id to contain the button in the Users#Index view

```
<div id ="follow_form_<%= user.id %>">
```